# Boss working on project creating errors

Tags: professionalism, management, communication

While I was on vacation my boss worked on my software project trying to fix some things. What ended up happening is that nothing was really fixed and instead a bunch of bugs were created. This caused me a week of unnecessary work almost. This is not the first time this has happened. However, it happens far and between (mostly when I'm not around).

Since he is my boss this puts me in an awkward position. Next time he wants to work on it should I tell him to run any big changes through me and why? Should comment on this now? If it is brought up why it is taking me longer than usual should I bring this up (or should I just bring it up just in case it is crossing his mind)? If I do bring it up how should I do it while being respectful and professional?

Comment: why didn't you just revert the changes in source control?

Comment: I guess the problem was that I came back and worked on stuff for a few weeks and then realized a bunch of code was broken. So some of the code I had to revert but some of it I couldn't. It's a large project.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere No, but for the most part I have written 99% of the project and understand the system. So, it feels weird having to say that to a boss since it is not my place and could be considered rude. But, at the same time making changes to the code while not understanding how the system works as a whole can cause problems.

Comment: Well, you learned that whenever you come back from holiday, you have to check your source code control system if any changes were made. Could be worse; I've heard of places where you had to check how much RAM your development machine had after coming back from holiday.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with asking him to keep you in the loop, there is also nothing wrong with having backups of everything so you can roll back if need be.

If I were you I'd ask him to keep me in the loop with any changes and leave it at that. My own policy is to back up all my stuff regularly, and then people making changes are easy to revert to my last backup.

Comment: You have to know your boss, but if he's not the kind of person to admit being wrong, switching back to a backup position is the less costly solution for you.

Comment: When you come back from vacation, check the version control logs and see what he did.

Comment: @AmyBlankenship Yes, that is obvious now...